# Convert Google Sheet to CSV then attach it to an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple Apps Script need, but can't find a near enough sample from the community.
I need to convert 2 sheets from a Google Spreadsheet, individually, as CSV files then attach them in an email.
So far, I found a script to convert a sheet into a CSV format and file it in a folder.
I looked for a script to add that will instead attach the CSV file to an email, but can't find anything which I can use based on my novice level of Apps Script knowledge.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Script:

```
function sheet1ToCsv()
{
    var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
    var sheet_Name = "xxxx"

    var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet_Name)
    var sheetNameId = sheet.getSheetId().toString();

    params= ssID+"/export?gid="+sheetNameId +"&format=csv"
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ params
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData);  

    var folderId = "yyyy";
    var csvContent = {
    title: sheet_Name+".csv",
    mimeType: "application/vnd.csv",  
    parents: [{id: folderId}]
     }
    var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(csvContent,result)

}
```

Comment: It looks that the question needs more focus, details and clarity. Please bear in mind that we know nothing about your "novice level". Have you ever write by yourself a script in Google Apps Script? What is the source of the code included in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, an email is not sent. And, only one CSV file is created to Google Drive. From `I need to convert 2 sheets from a Google Spreadsheet, individually, as CSV files then attach them in an email.` and your showing script, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var emailAddress = "###"; // Please set your email address.
  var sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]; // Please set your 2 sheet names you want to use.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var requestData = { "method": "GET", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  var blobs = sheetNames.map(s => {
    var params = ssID + "/export?gid=" + ss.getSheetByName(s).getSheetId() + "&format=csv";
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + params;
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData).getBlob().setName(s); // <--- Modified
  });
  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: emailAddress, subject: "sample subject", body: "sample body", attachments: blobs });
}
```

- When this script is run, an email is sent by including 2 CSV files as the attachment files.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike for your usual prompt response and help.
Is there a short code to add in order to name the sheets individually, for example "Report 1" and "Report 2". At the moment the filenames of the attached files are both "export.csv".
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Angelito Saliva Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Is there a short code to add in order to name the sheets individually, for example "Report 1" and "Report 2". At the moment the filenames of the attached files are both "export.csv".`, I modified the above script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Angelito Saliva If you want to add the extension of `.csv`, please use `return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestData).getBlob().setName(s + ".csv");`.

Comment: yes the extension .csv worked perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Angelito Saliva Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const names = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const params = { "method": "GET", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  let bA = [];
  names.forEach(n => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?gid=" + sh.getSheetId() + "&format=csv";
    let r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    let csv = r.getContentText();
    let file = folder.createFile(n, csv, MimeType.CSV);
    bA.push(file.getBlob());
  })
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, { attachments: bA })
}
```